# Docker different environment variables for the same service

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm currently building a web scraper with python. But in order to access the specific page, I need an API key and the key is severely limited in terms of requests. So, my idea is to create the python script and set the API key as environment variable for each container. That way, I can scrape with greater throughput.

Now, my question:

I know that you can set environment variables through the `docker-compose.yml` but by doing so, it doesn't make that file shareable through a public repo on git. Is there a better way to set environment variable for each container than through the compose file? I'm thinking with `.env` files but that makes it a nightmare in the python script as a I have to name each file differently in my folder.

This is what my compose file looks like for now

```
version: '3'
services:
  user-list_1:
    build: .
    environment:
      - API_KEY="1212_323131-23"
  user-list_2:
    build: .
    environment:
      - API_KEY="API_KEYFOR2"
```

Comment: `env_file` can be whatever name you want.

Comment: I tried with 
```
env_file:
  - .env.container1
```
but this means that `.env.container1` is copied into the container no? and if i use `load_dotenv` it won't work

Comment: load_dotenv is a Python function? If so, you'd use Docker volumes instead. Otherwise, you only need os.env

Comment: ah, i miss read the docs. I thought that when you load the .env from the docker-compose I would need to use `load_dotenv` but turns out they are already set in the container. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply use the `env_file` option in the `docker-compose.yml`, it will set the environment variables for that container directly. No need to read a `.env`in python. The code looks like this:

```
version: '3'
services:
  scraper-1:
    build: .
    ports:
    - "9999:5000"
    env_file:
      - .env.container1
  scraper-2:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8888:5000"
    env_file:
      - .env.container2
```